# Как сделать блок неоднотонного цвета, не используя картинку?

Tags: html, css

Например, плавный переход с одного цвета на другой.

Answer (score 1):

Может, вот так: [Кроссбраузерный CSS-градиент](http://www.webmasters.by/articles/html-coding/131-cross-browser-css-gradient.html)?

Answer (score 0):

HTML5 и CSS3, например: 
[Линейный градиент](http://webref.ru/layout/html5-css3/background/linear-gradient)  
[Радиальный градиент](http://webref.ru/layout/html5-css3/background/radial-gradient)